# Taco Android build Error

Tags: android, html, cordova, taco

I just started learning building andoriod apps using Microsoft's open source software called `taco`, and I followed the steps they have on `taco.tools` and the problem comes when I use the Command `taco build android` I get the error `No install build tools found` , `Error:cmd: commmad failed with exit code 1`. I have however installed the build tools and checked if they were installed via the sdk manager.

Please see images

[image: Sdk manager]

and also

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have two installs of the Android SDK. To fix: set your environment variable ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Insight\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk

This issue is caused by Visual Studio installing the SDK into AppData, and Taco installing the SDK into Program Files.

Comment: I up-voted because Joshua noticed that you have two Android SDKs installed. The one your build output references is using your existing Android_Home directory of c:\program files\... which probably doesn't have the right build tools installed.  However your screenshot with the SDK manager shows that the SDK installed in c:\users\insight\... does have the build tools installed. Changing your Android_Home path makes sense.

Comment: Hey @JoshuaSkelton & Steve Kennedy    Thank you for your swift replies, I changed the Android_home directory and that fixed the initial error, however I now have another one which has to do with the gradle. The Error says "Unable to start daemon process" Error could not create java virtual machine. it also gave the gradle.org site to go read up a bit so in the mean time i will do so